# Conditional Rendering with React-Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**1. Context**

The code is used within a Sign Up page in order to conditionally render either a Sign Up form or a form into which to enter a Confirmation Code so that the user's email address can be confirmed. AWS Amplify is used to create the User Account within a User Pool, as well confirming the email address.


**2. Problem**

Either form does not render when being called upon.


**3. All Additional Source Code**

https://github.com/pimp-my-book/FDWA

**4. Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";
import { Button, Form, Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

const SignUp = ( ) => {
    const [ username, setUsername ] = useState("");
    const [ password, setPassword ] = useState("");
    const [ confirmationCode, setConfirmationCode ] = useState("");
    const [ newUser, setNewUser ] = useState(null);

    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const newUser = await Auth.signUp(username, password);
            console.log(newUser);
            setNewUser(newUser)
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.message)
        }
    }

    const handleConfirmationSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            await Auth.confirmSignUp(username, confirmationCode);
            await Auth.signIn(username, password)
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.message)
        }
    }

    const renderForm = () => {
        return(
          <Container>
              <Row>
                  <Col>
                    <div>
                        Sign Up
                    </div>
                  </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                  <Form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
                    <Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group controlId="sign-up-email">
                            <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="email"
                                    placeholder="Please enter your email address here..."
                                    value={ username }
                                    onChange = { e => setUsername( e.target.value ) }
                                />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group controlId="sign-up-password">
                            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Please enter your password here..."
                                    value={ password }
                                    onChange = { e => setPassword( e.target.value ) }
                                />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group controlId="sign-up-password">
                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                Submit
                            </Button>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                  </Form>
              </Row>
          </Container>  
        );
    }

    const renderConfirmationForm = () => {
        return(
            <Container>
                <Row>
                  <Col>
                    <div>
                        Confirmation Code
                    </div>
                  </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                  <Form onSubmit={ handleConfirmationSubmit }>
                      <Form.Row>
                          <Form.Group controlId="confirmation-code-input">
                              <Form.Label>We've sent a Confirmation Code to your Email Address -_-</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Please enter your Code here..."
                                    value={ confirmationCode }
                                    onChange={ e => setConfirmationCode( e.target.value ) }
                                />
                          </Form.Group>
                      </Form.Row>
                      <Form.Row>
                          <Form.Group controlId="confirmation-code-button">
                              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                  Confirm Your Code
                              </Button>
                          </Form.Group>
                      </Form.Row>
                  </Form>
              </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                newUser === null
                ? <renderForm/>
                : <renderConfirmationForm/>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default SignUp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `renderConfirmationForm` and `renderForm` are functions you don't have to use jsx and instead just call the functions, it will perform a little better and make for a cleaner overview in react dev tools:

```
return (
  <div>
    {newUser === null
      ? renderForm()
      : renderConfirmationForm()}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank You for your solution, it worked perfectly. Both forms are rendering and no issues spotted so far.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use capital letter for Component name

```
const RenderForm=()=>{....}

const RenderConfirmationForm=()=>{....}
```

Comment: Thank You for your help, your solution worked but only partially. The forms rendered but the input fields only took one character and then refused to take anymore input.

The solution below was a perfect fix however, Thanks again.