# How to show temporary message in ReactJS until API endpoint comes back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my **helperfile.js** file, I have an react bootstrap and overlay trigger as follows. The `flaskResult` variable is a prop that is passed in.

```
  const popover = (
    <Popover id="popover-basic">
      <Popover.Header as="h3">Num Nodes</Popover.Header>
      <Popover.Body>
        The number of nodes is: {flaskResult}
      </Popover.Body>
    </Popover>
  );
...
          <OverlayTrigger rootClose trigger="click" placement="left" overlay={popover}>
            <Button variant="outline-primary"  onClick = { (e) => {onCallEndpoint({endpoint:"get_num_nodes"})}} >Count Num Nodes</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
```

Notice that the Button calls an `onCallEndpoint`. That endpoint hits a flask API to do some computations. Some computations are very quick and the result is almost instant. Others are very slow and the result takes several seconds.

How would I show "processing" or a spinning circle while flask executes?

Here's the api call in **app.js**

```
  const onCallEndpoint = async (props) => {
    const {endpoint} = props;
    try {
        const flow = reactFlowInstance.toObject();
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
        const response = await fetch(
          `${serverUrl}/${props.endpoint}`,
          {
            headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify(flow),
          }
        );
  
        const responseData = await response.json();
        setFlaskResult(responseData.message);
      } catch (error) {
        setFlaskResult(error.message);
      }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Conditional Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263341/react-conditional-rendering)

Comment: Not really. The logic here is based on a reactHook that needs to be updated by a call to an endpoint. I'm not sure how to check that it actually has been updated.

Comment: The concept should be the same. Have a state variable that indicates if the API has returned. Use conditional rendering based on that state to determine whether to render a processing message/spinning circle or the data from the API call. I'm not sure the exact details using hooks, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921355/conditional-rendering-with-react-hooks maybe this instead?

Comment: If neither of those are exactly what you want, I hope I've given you some words you can google.

Comment: Your two responses helped. If anyone ever reads this in the future: I added a `setFlaskResult("Processing")` right at the top of my endpoint call (before the fetch). Then in the div, I check if the string is "processing" and conditionally render. Works well.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a separate boolean flag rather than a string.

Comment: yes, but then I need to pass in two props.

Comment: Also, feel free to post your solution as an answer below. Future readers will find it much more easily that way.

Comment: And one more option: `setFlaskResult(null)`. Along with appropriate conditional rendering.

Comment: In fact, you might not even need the `setFlaskResult()` call. I think `useFlaskResult()` takes a default value, right? I'm out of date and not 100% sure how hooks work.

Comment: setting to null works well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone:

I overloaded the API call:

```
  const onCallEndpoint = async (props) => {
    const {endpoint} = props;
    setFlaskResult(null);
    try {
        const flow = reactFlowInstance.toObject();
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
        const response = await fetch(
          `${serverUrl}/${props.endpoint}`,
          {
            headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify(flow),
          }
        );
  
        const responseData = await response.json();
        
        setFlaskResult(responseData.message);
      } catch (error) {
        setFlaskResult(error.message);
      }
};
```

Then in popover I did the following:

```
 const popover = (
    <Popover id="popover-basic">
      <Popover.Header as="h3">Num Nodes</Popover.Header>
      <Popover.Body>
      The number of nodes is: {(flaskResult) ? flaskResult:"Computing!"}.
        
      </Popover.Body>
    </Popover>
  );
```